# Python3 Typerror: replace() argument 1 must be str, not int

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying a few days now to get this code to work on MacOS but with no success. Can you please have a look at and see what I'm missing?

Running python 3.6 and I've uploaded the whole code. Thanks a lot

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from __future__ import print_function
try:
    import pymarketcap
    import decimal
    from operator import itemgetter
    import argparse
except Exception as e:
    print('Make sure to install {0} (pip3 install {0}).'.format(str(e).split("'")[1]))
    exit()

# arguments and setup
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-m','--minimum_vol',type=float,help='Minimum Percent volume per exchange to have to count',default=1)
parser.add_argument('-p','--pairs',nargs='*',default=[],help='Pairs the coins can be arbitraged with - default=all')
parser.add_argument('-c','--coins_shown',type=int,default=10,help='Number of coins to show')
parser.add_argument('-e','--exchanges',nargs='*',help='Acceptable Exchanges - default=all',default=[])
parser.add_argument('-s','--simple',help='Toggle off errors and settings',default=False,action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()
cmc = pymarketcap.Pymarketcap()
info = []
count = 1
lowercase_exchanges = [x.lower() for x in args.exchanges]
all_exchanges = not bool(args.exchanges)
all_trading_pairs = not bool(args.pairs)
coin_format = '{: <25} {: >6}% {: >10} {: >15} {: <10} {: <10} {: <15} {: <5}'

if not args.simple:
    print('CURRENT SETTINGS\n* MINIMUM_PERCENT_VOL:{}\n* TRADING_PAIRS:{}\n* COINS_SHOWN:{}\n* EXCHANGES:{}\n* ALL_TRADING_PAIRS:{}\n* ALL_EXCHANGES:{}\n'.format(args.minimum_vol,args.pairs,args.coins_shown,lowercase_exchanges,all_trading_pairs,all_exchanges))
# retrieve coin data
for coin in cmc.ticker():
    try:
        markets = cmc.markets(coin["id"])
    except Exception as e:
        markets = cmc.markets(coin["symbol"])
    best_price = 0

    best_exchange = ''
    best_pair = ''
    worst_price = 999999
    worst_exchange = ''
    worst_pair = ''
    has_markets = False
    for market in markets:
        trades_into = market["pair"].replace (coin["symbol"]," ").replace("-"," ")
        if market['percent_volume'] >= args.minimum_vol and market['updated'] and (trades_into in args.pairs or all_trading_pairs) and (market['exchange'].lower() in lowercase_exchanges or all_exchanges):
            has_markets = True
            if market['price_usd'] >= best_price:
                best_price = market['price_usd']
                best_exchange = market['exchange']
                best_pair = trades_into
            if market['price_usd'] <= worst_price:
                worst_price = market['price_usd']
                worst_exchange = market['exchange']
                worst_pair = trades_into
    if has_markets:
        info.append([coin['name'],round((best_price/worst_price-1)*100,2),worst_price,worst_exchange,worst_pair,best_price,best_exchange,best_pair])
    elif not args.simple:
        print(coin['name'],'had no markets that fit the criteria.')

    print('[{}/100]'.format(count),end='\r')
    count += 1

# show data
info = sorted(info,key=itemgetter(1))[::-1]
print(coin_format.format("COIN","CHANGE","BUY PRICE","BUY AT","BUY WITH","SELL PRICE","SELL AT","SELL WITH"))
for coin in info[0:args.coins_shown]:
    print(coin_format.format(*coin))#
```

also link - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ec0643e0b27f33cf628fdafce29a698c

The error that I keep getting is this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run", line 45, in <module>
    trades_into = market["pair"].replace(coin["symbol"],"").replace("-","")
TypeError: replace() argument 1 must be str, not int
```

Really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: What is it that you don't understand in the error message exactly ??? It tells you __EXACTLY__ what and where the problem is...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your error is telling you all you need to know `coin["symbol"]` is an int, but `replace` accepts only Strings. You can fix this by doing `str(coin["symbol"])`

Answer (score 2):

It says the argument you are passing is not in correct format, requires string and you have passed int

write this

```
trades_into = market["pair"].replace(str(coin["symbol"])," ").replace("-"," ")
```

instead of

```
trades_into = market["pair"].replace (coin["symbol"]," ").replace("-"," ")
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Unfortunately I can only select 1 answer.